# How to solve ReverseNoMatch error django?

Tags: python, django, url

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'infos'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_page, name='index_view'),
    path('members/', views.list_members, name='list_members'),
    path('members/<int:id>/', views.view_member, name='view_member'),
    path('members/<int:id>/photos/', views.show_photos, name='show_photos'),
]
```

## views.py

```
def show_photos(request, id):

    member = BandMembers.objects.get(pk=id)
    member_id = member.pk
    print(member_id)
    photos = Photos.objects.get(band_member=member)
    return render(request, 'infos/photos.html', { 'photos': photos, 'member': member_id})
```

## html template photos.html

```
{%  extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    Στοιχεία
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <a href="{% url 'infos:show_photos' id %}" class="btn btn-primary"> Φωτογραφίες </a>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I get a `NoReserveMatch` error. What am i doing wrong? I've been searching for hours and hours at Stackoverflow, Youtube,... and it seems as if i'm doing it right. But surely I DON'T !!!!!!

Where is my mistake ??????? Thank you guys .

Comment: What is `id` in that template? You don't have a variable with that name. Did you mean `member`?

Comment: i'v tried all : member , member.id , member.pk everything !!

Comment: When do you get the error? What is the URL you are ettempting?

Comment: Try the regular expression format maybe ?

Comment: Can you post the full trace back?

Comment: you are missing /photos in ` <a href="{% url 'infos:show_photos' id %}` you need to provide photos to your url too

Comment: Show the code you used with "member". That is the correct answer, so if you did that you would not get the error any more.